How to define a metric using SQL to get last month sum value in clickhouse
I have a clickhouse table named posts:
Period date; objectCode String; typeName String; amount numeric;

I want to get a result using SQL:
select toStartOfMonth(Period) as pt, objectCode, sum(amount) as ThisMonthValue, ??? as PreviousMonthValue
from posts
group by pt, objectCode

How to write this SQL to get PreviousMonthValue? I want to get metric definition from configuration file, such as 'sum(amount) as ThisMonthValue'; and dynamically generate SQL statements

In Microsoft Dax, We can use calculate('Metric', filter(to_monty('date') = last_Month_Value)) to get the previous month metric Value. The filter statement will replace filter in column 'date', and set a new filter. These are the key.

you need to use range frame https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/window-functions#moving--sliding-average-per-10-seconds
     any(MonthValue) OVER (PARTITION BY objectCode ORDER BY toRelativeMonthNum(pt) 
          Range BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS prevMonthValue

https://fiddle.clickhouse.com/87441738-ecf0-42e4-aef7-e8c3b27b24e2
https://fiddle.clickhouse.com/34523546-c5e4-40d0-a922-3ce83df516da
SELECT
    pt,
    objectCode,
    MonthValue,
    any(MonthValue) OVER (PARTITION BY objectCode ORDER BY toRelativeMonthNum(pt) ASC 
               RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS prevMonthValue
FROM
(
    SELECT
        toStartOfMonth(period) AS pt,
        objectCode,
        sum(amount) AS MonthValue
    FROM T
    GROUP BY
        pt,
        objectCode
)
ORDER BY
    pt ASC,
    objectCode ASC

